# return 'pass' iteration through a method python

Tags: python, python-2.7

is there any pythonic way to return a 'pass' iteration from a method such has:

```
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, np.nan, 4]

for q in x:

    if np.isnan(q):
        pass
    else:
        print q
1
2
4
```

I am trying to achieve (in a more complex code) something like:

```
import numpy as np
x = [1, 2, np.nan, 4]

def skip(var):
    if np.isnan(var):
        return pass
    else:
        return var

for q in x:
    var(q)
    print q
```

any way to make that work? passing an iteration trough a method?

Comment: simply `pass` or `return None` or `return`

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a `pass` but you can just do `return` which will implicitly `return None` You can then use None in the calling code to check whether it was passed or not.

Comment: Just do `if q is not None:`

Comment: I'm not really sure why you want this, It'd be better altogether to just do `for q in x: if not np.isnan(q): print(q)`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass a flag from the method skip to the for loop. There is no way to pass off a pass.

As others have noted, return implicitly returns None.

Being that you are not mutating the variable, it's safe to nest the part of the loop after you run your function within an if block.

```
def skip(var):
    if not np.isnan(var):
        return var

for q in x:
    if var(q):
        print q
```

Comment: In this implementation, if you do anything in your method skip that you want to remain changed, you need to set a variable equal to skip(var) then check if it's None/whatever flag you use, in that for loop's if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `filter`?

```
for q in filter(lambda z: not np.isnan(z), x):
    # put the rest of your code here
    print q
```

`filter` is fairly pythonic and lightweight and make sure your loop block only has to worry about positive cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
def skip(var):
    if np.isnan(var):
        return None
    else:
        return var

for q in x:
    result = skip(q)
    if result != None:
         var(result)
    print q
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there is multiple answer to this but I found out that `continue` was what I was looking for such has:

import numpy as np

```
x = [1, 2, np.nan, 4]

def skip(var):
    return np.isnan(var)


for q in x:
    if skip(q)
       continue
    print q
```